# Calculation of $\operatorname{trace}(L^THL)$, $L$ is lower triangular, $H$ is symmetric.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I am working on a problem where I had to find the following expression:
$$ \ell = \operatorname{Tr}(P'HP)$$

I already modified my model formulation using cholesky decomposition for PSD matrices and came up with equivalent expression with $L$ instead of $P.$

$$ \ell\,' = \operatorname{Tr}(L'HL)$$
Where,

$L$ is lower triangular and $H$ is symmetric. How can I compute this fast? I do not want to compute the full product and then take trace since they are huge matrices.

I tried to decompose $H$ into a lower and an upper triangular matrix, but it doesn't help.

Comment: It is strange Cholesky with simply a symmetric $H$. Maybe $H$ is diagonal?

Comment: No, $H$ is just a symmetric matrix.

Comment: You could rearrange $l' = \mathrm{Tr} (L' H L) = \mathrm{Tr} (L L' H)$ and then use the method for symmetric matrices described in http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2011/05/25/computing-the-trace-of-a-product-of-matrices.html .

Comment: I think your comment really helps, I am going to try this. The link is also useful, although I need to figure out myself as how this works.

Comment: For a slightly more detailed explanation of why $\mathrm{Tr} A B$ is the same as the sum of Hadamard (elementwise) product of $A$ and $B^T$, [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_%28matrices%29#Properties) might also be of some use.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a practical method or not, but you may evaluate the trace probabilistically. If $x$ is a random vector whose entries are i.i.d. standard normal, then $\operatorname{trace}(A)=E(x^TAx)$.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the complexity of the calculation is $\Theta(n^3)$.

Let $L=[L_{i,j}],H=[H_{i,j}]$. Thus $tr(L^THL)=\sum_{i,j,k}L_{j,i}H_{j,k}L_{k,i}=\sum_{j,k}<L_j,L_k>H_{j,k}$ where $<L_j,L_k>$ is the scalar product of $L_j$ and $L_k$ -the rows of $L$ of indices $j,k$-. Since the $(H_{j,k})$ do not depend on $L$, the searched complexity is the one of the calculation of the $(<L_j,L_k>)_{j\leq k}$. I do not see how to do better than $\Theta(n^3)$; indeed, a priori, there are no relations linking the $(<L_j,L_k>)_{j\leq k}$.

EDIT. About the user1551's post. Each calculation of $x^TL^THLx$ has complexity $O(n^2)$. Let $n=200$; a sample of $10^5$ tests gives an error $\approx 1.5$%; a sample of $200$ tests does not give any significant digit. Unfortunately, it seems that the number of tests is necessarily much greater than $O(n)$.